# Analyzing a .dmp crash file?

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps

I tried traditional ways and answers to analyze my .DMP files. WinDbg doesn`t take it, it outputs:

> Could not find the C:\program files\softwaredir\dumps\dumpname_0313.rsa.dmp
>
> File, Win32 error 0n87

It's an Multi Theft Auto: San Andreas crash dump. .rsa.dmp

Why doesn`t WinDbg take it, does it have to do with a certain dump type?

If anyone would want to try opening, [here is the dumpfile with the issue](https://mega.co.nz/#!AZ8VERxK!Z3qpiuyS_-G7XRo3Pj6_f0iDtIdwHuZH7MrN5wkaX2w)

I would like to know if you have the solution to solve the opening problem/or any other tool to open the dump.

But I really need the exception that caused the crash, so either I'll need advise on how to open it or if I can fix it.

For case 2 (can't solve it for me here) the crash memory locations are:

```
Version  1.3.5-release 6078.0.000
Time  Tue Jan 21 03:13:18 2014
Module  C:\Program Files (x86)\MTA San Andreas 1.3\mods\deathmatch\client.dll
Code  0 x C0000005
Offset  0 x 0009E796

EAX 00000000 EBX 30994AB0 ECX 21E82218 EDX 0028F71C ESI 3098E520
EDI 6FBBCCC9 EBP 0028F7BC ESP 0028F6F4 EIP 1B00E796 FLG 00210246
CS 0023 DS 002B SS 002B ES 002B FS 0053 GS 002B
```

Comment: That is definitely not a valid Windows .DMP file as it is missing the standard `MDMP` or `PAGEDU` file header. What application created the file?

Comment: No its not an windows fault dump, it's an application crash from and made by Multi Theft Auto: San Andreas. But many (developers) can just open these dumps... so how cant I

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to generate and analyze a dump file:

- Downloaded [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) (a free Sysinternals tool)
- Created a folder `c:\dumps`
- Added ProcDump to `PATH`
- Entered `procdump -ma -i c:\dumps` into command prompt to start the JustInTime debugger
- Opened the dump file in visual studio

Using this method we were able to resolve a difficult bug and determine what exception was causing my machine to crash.

Comment: I asked this a long time ago and i already found the problem why i couln't open the dump, the specific application generates and .rsa'd the dump (encrypted) for security, now I could open them using the raw dump, variant non-encrypted. Thanks for the reply though.